# Can the Arduino Eclipse plugin v2.2 be used with Arduino 1.5.8?

Tags: eclipse

It keeps giving me this warning:

> You are using a version of the Arduino IDE that is newer than available at the release of this plugin.`

Does this means I need to use a night build?

Answer (score 1):

V2.2 is pretty old by now.
As far as I recall it should work fine.

V2.2 of the Arduino eclipse plugin should work fine with the Arduino IDE version 1.5.8. 
What that phrase wants to say is: the plugin V2.2 was released before Arduino IDE 1.5.8 was released; as such the code can not make a statement on the compatibility.

But again V2.2 is old. We hope to release V3.0 end of February 2016

Comment: Doesn't the warning just mean that Eclipse might be old, not the Arduino IDE? Getting a nightly build of the IDE would make things worse, wouldn't it?

Comment: Hi Nick.
IMHO The writer is referring to using the nightly of the arduino eclipse plugin (which is currently at V3) and not the "hourly" of the arduino IDE.
Note that the stable release of the arduino plugin is 2.4.

Comment: To clarify your answer `it should work fine` - do you mean the nightly build, or that V2.2 should work fine?

Comment: V2.2 of the arduino eclipse plugin should work fine with the arduino IDE version 1.5.8. As the statement says: the plugin V2.2 was released before arduino IDE 1.5.8 was released as such I could not make a statement on the compatibilty. But again V2.2 is old. We hope to release V3.0 this week

Comment: @jantje Could you please include more details to your answer, it's fairly short right now.